# Batch command to determine appropriate system folder and move .ocx files there, then register file

Tags: batch-file, copy, move, ocs

I need to create an easy to use method for users to install .ocx files in their system folder, be it System32 or SysWOW64, and then register the file.

I was able to follow directions and register the file after manually moving it to the system folder, but I need to make all of it occur automatically. How can i make it work for both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of windows?

Thanks!

Comment: So basically, your question is: *How can I determine whether or not my Windows is the 64-bit version?*; is that true?

Comment: Some code examples of what you have tried so far might help you get answers faster.

Comment: If you have a problem, which isn't in your post, then you do nothing different. Windows will sort it out. You've asked for a generic solution to an unknown problem. An answer has to be an essay covering all possibilities.

Comment: I'm not sure how my question is unclear. I want a batch script to move an ocx file from the desktop to the system folder, and then register the file it just moved. My problem is that I don't know how to allow the script to determine whether the system is 32 or 64 bit, so it can move the ocx file to the correct system folder.